# Batch file to open multiple folders at once IN THE ORDER I WANT

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch file to open several folders at once. Only, they always open in different order. How to get them to open in the order I want [image: Music1, Music2, Music3, Music4]

```
@echo off
start /max explorer "D:\Music1"
start /max explorer "E:\Music2 - EDIT"
start /max explorer "H:\Music3"
start /max explorer "H:\Music4 - EDIT"
```

Comment: See this [answer over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1683808/774709).

Comment: Thanks, adding  timeout /t 2 >nul worked.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments:

```
@echo off
start /max explorer "D:\Music1"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start /max explorer "E:\Music2 - EDIT"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start /max explorer "H:\Music3"
timeout /t 2 >nul
start /max explorer "H:\Music4 - EDIT"
```